# For next mit Controls

Tags: vba, userform

I have different query levels (referred to as "LPGP" 1-40) and Label referred to as "BalkenZ" 1-40. The initial value is "JGesZ".
As a formula I have

```
For X = 1 To 40
    Y = 10 + X

    If JGesZ >= Controls("LBGP" & X) Then    'Abfrage der Werte
        Controls("Label_BalkenZ" & Y).Visible = True  'Balken sichtbar
        Controls("Label_BalkenZ" & Y).BackColor = Farbe03 'Festlegen der Hintergrundfarbe
    Else
        Controls("Label_BalkenZ" & Y).Visible = False 'Balken ausgeblendet
    End If
Next X
```

It is always answered with a runtime error at the start.
What is wrong?

Runtime Error '-2147024809 (8007005)':
the specified object could not be found

Comment: Hello KSM welcome to StackOverflow, this is the english site, you should post your questions in english so we all can help you.

Comment: Guten Tag und willkommen bei Stack Overflow! Sprechen Sie Englisch? Non-English posts have a tendency of ending up closed as "unclear", unfortunately. Please [edit] /translate your question, if possible. Cheers!

Comment: What error is giving to you? Where is the code highlighted?

Comment: @DisplayName [relevant meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/1188513)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, I'll be fired!

Comment: For one thing, if X > 30, then Y will be > 40 and based on your description, Controls("Label_BalkenZ" & Y) will be out of bounds.

Comment: On witch side can i tell question in German or other languist?

Comment: Ich finde keine Flagge wo ich meine Sprache einstellen kann.